# Node.js Express - prevent access to certain URLs

Tags: node.js, express

I want to prevent access to someone not logged-in to any url that starts with '/users'

Here's my current code:

```
app.use('/^users*',function (req, res, next) {
    if (checkAuth(req)) { 
        console.log('authorization OK');
        next(); 
    } else {
        console.log('authorization failed');
        res.redirect('/login');
    }

});

function checkAuth(req) {
    console.log('req',req.url);
    if (!req.session.user_id && req.url !== '/login' && req.url !== '/') {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
};
```

but the regular expression I have is not right. I can't find a regular expression for expression that matches "everything that starts with 'user'". This should be easy, but is proving more difficult than expected.

According to the Express API documentation:

```
// will match paths starting with /abcd
app.use('/abcd', function (req, res, next) {
  next();
})
```

Answer (score 3):

```
app.all('*/users/*', requireAuthentication, function (req, res, next){

});
```

Above route will catch all kind of requests starting from *users*, will through *requireAuthentication* function, then following function on *next()*.

Answer (score 1):

Try `app.use('/users/?*', function(){});` That should match all routes starting with `/users`

Comment: What doesn't work? Does it never go into the middleware? And what is the url you are testing?

Comment: I edited the question. According to the documentation the regular expression '/user' should capture everything that starts with 'user', but in fact it only captures the exact string 'user'.

Comment: if I leave out the regular expression altogether, and just do app.use(function(req,res,next)){} it goes through the middleware and will capture everything (all urls). So I know my code is otherwise good. There is something wrong with the regular expression.

Comment: my express version is 1.4.23

Comment: `/user` on its own won't capture stuff like `/user/profile` also you seem to be using `/user` and `/users` at the same time. Make sure its the correct url.

Comment: Express is almost on version 5, you should consider upgrading as well :)

Comment: aight will upgrade before anything

Comment: 1.4.23, is version 4, I am on latest version

Answer (score 1):

Do not use single quote marks `'/^users*'` use `/^\/users*`. That is for all strings beginning with `'/users'`.

But if just want it to be hierarchial as `'/users/foo'` you **do not need regex** you could use:

```
app.use('/users/*',function (req, res, next)
```

[app.use express API reference](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.use)

Comment: Your answer says not to use single quote marks and then the code you propose uses single quote marks.  You got me confused.

Comment: yeah thats if you dont want regex, i'll make it clearer in my answer