# How do I restrict the node URL to open in browser

Tags: node.js, url

Anyone can see node's app.js files in browser. 
Suppose there is node url http://1.2.3.4:3000. When I write http://1.2.3.4:3000/server.js or by creating domain virtual host like abc.lmn:3000/server.js, it shows me complete file as it is.

How do I restrict to open the file in URL?
Please help...

Comment: have a look on http://stackoverflow.com/a/27467829/5692251

Comment: Thanks  nmnsud! It worked for me..
I implement this like:

//Restrict the files to open in browser/postman directly
app.all(['*server.js*', '*Config/**', '*Models/**', '*package.json*', '*bower.json*', '*README.md*', '*Public/**'], function (req, res, next){
    res.send({ auth: false });
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved in adding below small script in main server.js file

```
app.all(['*server.js*', '*Config/**', '*Models/**', '*package.json*', '*bower.json*', '*README.md*', '*Public/**'], function (req, res, next) {
        res.send({auth: false})
})
})
```

Thank you once again nmnsud..